# where does nativescript look for modules?

Tags: nativescript

where does nativescript look for modules as I read in http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm the order for `nodejs` is like this:

(I don't have problem with relative paths,the problem is when no file path is used)

1-First, Node.js looks to see if the given module is a core module then in node_modules in this order:

for example for `var utils = require( "utils" );` it like this :

```
 ./node_modules/utils.js
 ./node_modules/utils/index.js
 ./node_modules/utils/package.json
```

what about in nativescript what is the order of locations it looks for modues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would just npm to manage all your dependencies from the project root. NativeScript uses commonJS, so npm is used to distribute plugins. You can find out more [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/details/using-npm-modules-and-nativescript-plugins).

There are a number of slightly different approaches:

### NPM Modules:

So to add the [Nativescript OAuth](https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth) you would run `npm install knock-knock-jokes --save` in the project root and then in the app `var knockknock = require('knock-knock-jokes')` would work.

### NativeScript Plugins:

For Nativescript specific plugins, you can run `tns plugin add nativescript-oauth` for most nativescript applications, this will keep all dependencies recorded in your **package.json** file also.

### With TypeScript

Also, you might like to use TypeScript to enable IntelliSense etc. In which case the syntax would be more like `import * as tnsOAuthModule from 'nativescript-oauth';` and if the module doesn't have a definition file shipped with it on npm, then you might like to use the [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) which will manage your typescript definitions.